# The dirichlet and harmonic functions why they are important

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I am wondering why finding a function  that is harmonic on the sphere and that respect some conditions on the frontiere of the sphere is important ?

- This is called the Dirichlet problem, and I don't understand why we are interesting in this problem ?
- Why are we want the function to be harmonic ?

I know what it means for a function to be harmonic, but I don't understand what is the "advantage" of being harmonic. Moreover does the solution of the Dircihlet helps solving real-life/physic problems ?

Thank you !

Comment: It is very useful in particular in solving differential equations.

Comment: A big reason is being able to use conformal maps from disk to other domains, you end up with solutions to different problems. Like a harmonic function in the upper half plane.